# How to convert this kind of nested for loops to CUDA C++ for parallel programing?

Tags: c++, cuda

this is what I tried. difficult to find better indexing... This nested for loop somewhat difficult to solve.

```
    int k=0;
    for (int m=0; m<7; i++) // outer loop
    {   
      for(int j=0; j<100; j++) // inner loop 1
      {a[k] = b[m] + c[j];
      k++;
      }

      for(int j=0; j<100; j++) // inner loop 2
      {a[k] = b[m] - c[j];
      k++;
      }

    }
```

Comment: If you can't take the time to post correct code, why should people take the (significantly more) time to try and answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example code, the loop iterations appear to be independent, which makes things easier.

We can start by counting the total number of iterations: 8*(100+100) = 1600.

Therefore we would want to spin up a grid of at least 1600 threads if we want to fully distribute the work.

Your `m` variable doesn't seem to be loop-dependent, so `b[m]` is effectively a constant for the code you have shown.

Another planning item is to determine the indexing of `j` based on `k`, but that is also pretty easy, it is just `k%100`.

The final planning item is to account for the change in sign on `c` across loop iterations.  We can use `k/100` to help us determine this.

So we will create a globally unique thread index variable, and use that as our `k` variable:

```
__global__ void my_kernel(T1 *a, T2 *b, T3 *c, int N){

  int k = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  int m = <some value>;
  int j = k%100;
  if (k < N)
      a[k] = b[m] + ((k/100)&1)?(-c[j]):c[j];
}
```

Make sure to launch it with at least 1600 threads (in a 1D grid), passing 1600 for `N`.
`T1`, `T2`, `T3` could be typedefs for whatever types correspond to `a`, `b`, `c`.

Note that in your code you have this:

```
for(int j=0; j<100; j+=)
                      ^
                     This doesn't make sense to me.
```

So I have just pretended it was this instead:

```
for(int j=0; j<100; j++)
```

with the modification like this (not the same as what was edited into the question):

```
for (int m=0; m<7; m++) // outer loop
                   ^
```

The only change is to computation of the `m` variable:

```
__global__ void my_kernel(T1 *a, T2 *b, T3 *c, int N){

  int k = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  int m = k/200;  // change this line
  int j = k%100;
  if (k < N)
      a[k] = b[m] + ((k/100)&1)?(-c[j]):c[j];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Robert.....  Here there was a mistake made by me. mistakenly I typed i instead of m.                                                                              
     int k=0;
    for (int m=0; m<7; i++) // outer loop
    {   
      for(int j=0; j<100; j+=) // inner loop 1
      {a[k] = b[m] + c[j];
      k++;
      }

      for(int j=0; j<100; j+=) // inner loop 2
      {a[k] = b[m] - c[j];
      k++;
      }

    }

Comment: According to your comment, "Your m variable doesn't seem to be loop-dependent, so b[m] is effectively a constant for the code you have shown" you have taken it as a constant value. It was my fault and please give a solution for this requirement...